# Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute

Tags: d3.js

I am finding the error somewhere here:

```
d3.csv("Sales Export Friendly 2-14-2017.csv", function(data) {      
    var sales = []
    sales = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["BookingID"], +d["Total Paid"] ]; });

    var x = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(sales.map(function(sale){ return sale.bookingID; }))
        .range([0, width])
        .paddingInner([0.1])

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .domain([0, d3.max(sales.map(function(sale){ return sale['Total Paid']; }))]);
```

I believe it's something to do with the first mapping, which returns me an array of numeric arrays, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, `sales` is an array of arrays, it contains no objects.

That being said, it should be:

```
x.domain(sales.map(function(sale){ return sale[0]; }));
//index of the element in the inner array------^
```

And:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(sales, function(sale){ return sale[1];})]);
//index of the element in the inner array--------------^
```

Here is a demo with this bogus data:

```
bookingID,totalPaid
1,23
2,19
3,42
4,61
5,22
```

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

var sales = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d.bookingID, +d.totalPaid ]; });

var x = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain(sales.map(function(sale){ return sale[0]; }));
 
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(sales, function(sale){ return sale[1];})]);

console.log("x scale domain: " + x.domain());
console.log("y scale domain: " + y.domain());
```

```css
pre{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">bookingID,totalPaid
1,23
2,19
3,42
4,61
5,22</pre>
```

Comment: Can you explain the csvParse part of the code? When I tried adapting away from d3.csv to what you wrote, I got xxxx.csv is not a selector. I did manage to get a little further sticking with my  original code but using sale[0] and sale[1] for the x and y vars. It then displayed the axes' labels but bars don't show up and I get the same unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute error.

Comment: Ignore `d3.csvParse`, I'm using that because I cannot use `d3.csv` in a stack snippet. Just change the domain as I said. If you still got problems after fixing the scales that means you have additional issues. In that case, please post **another** question with the new problem.